# if checkbox is checked then take url from html data-url and open it in new tab with window.open()

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, foreach, checkboxlist

```html
<section class="main-checkboxes-section">
<div class="select-popup-divs">
<input
id="check-1"
type="checkbox"
class="css-checkbox"
checked
data-url="https://www.websitename.com/" />
<label for="check-1"><span>FIRST</span></label>
</div>

<div class="select-popup-divs">
<input
id="check-2"
ype="checkbox"
class="css-checkbox"
checked
data-url="https://www.websitename.com/" />
<label for="check-2"><span>SECOND</span></label>
</div>
</section>
```

```js
const fixedButton = document.querySelector('#fixed-open-id');

fixedButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.select-popup-divs');

allDivs.forEach((div) => {
const closestCheckbox = div.closest('.css-checkbox');

if (closestCheckbox.checked == true) {
indow.open(`${closestCheckbox.dataset.url}`);
}
});
});
```

on click of that button I expected for each div that has checkbox checked to open link in that checkbox's data-url but console says

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked')

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest: _"The closest() method of the Element interface **traverses the element and its parents** (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the specified CSS selector."_ - your `.select-popup-divs` elements do not match the `.css-checkbox` selector, and neither does any of their _parents_. You are walking in the wrong direction.

Comment: You wanted to use `querySelector` instead of `closest`

Comment: To select among the descendants of an element, you can call `querySelector` / `querySelectorAll` _on_ that element again. `div.querySelector('.css-checkbox');`